# what are mali.ko and ump.ko used for in lib/modules

Tags: android, module, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I found two kernel modules in /lib/modules folder, they are **mali.ko** and **ump.ko**,  and I tried to google some information about it, unfortunately, I found nothing valuable information.

if you have worked on those two kernel modules,  can you tell me what they are used for ?

thanks.

Comment: It looks like these are drivers for an ARM GPU.

Comment: I think it is GPU driver. Can anybody confirm?

Answer (score 1):

The Mali GPU kernel device driver [mali.ko] handles:

- Access to the Mali GPU hardware
- Interrupt handling
- Low level memory management

The UMP kernel device driver [ump.ko] handles:

- Access to allocated UMP memory through a secure ID. This enables memory to be shared across different applications, drivers and hardware components to facilitate zero-copy operations.
- The physical adress information required to set up an MMU or MPU table.
  {MMU= Memory Management Unit; MPU= Memory Protection Unit}
- A method to map UMP memory into CPU adress space, to enable reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

mali.ko : graphics processing unit for ARM ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mali_(GPU) )
ump.ko : that I do not know

Comment: Please post your answer with an explanation of what is in the link. Link-rot can occur, and then the link will be useless.